# Turn off screen with password protection but no sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, lock-screen

I want my pc to turn off the screen to save energy after 10 minutes
But i don't want the pc to sleep in case it's download or processing something.
And i want when i come back and the screen wake up, to have password protection ON.

So far i don't see how to do this from the control panel alone, is there a way to catch the waking up screen event and trigger a lock screen ?

Alternatively is there a way to track the CPU activity or memory significant acitivities and when both are idle for 10 minutes i can order a sleep?

Thank you

Comment: Well, first of all, if you have a password and the system set to ask for it at login, then it'll ask for the password whenever waking up from sleep or unlocking the screen. And you can edit the power plan you're using to "turn off the display" after 10min and  never "put the computer to sleep". Everything is available at the control panel. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelBay No, this question has a rather obvious answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would have to use a combination of two things here. Power settings and screensaver.

First, go in to power settings and set your computer to never go in to standby or hibernation. Next, set the screen to turn off after your desired period of time.

Now, go into personalization and enable a screensaver. Set the screensaver to kick in after the same amount of time as your display shuts off. Choose the option, “On resume, display login screen.”

As far as not letting the computer go to sleep until it is idle... I don’t think this is possible within the OS alone. There is probably a third party app out there, or you could definitely use a combination of writing your own app, script or scheduled task to do this. The first thing that comes to mind is that you can create a scheduled task that will only run if the computer is idle. That task could put the computer to sleep. I don’t know what “idle” is, as the computer is always doing something. But, it’s a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, turn off the sleep mode in advanced power settings.
Then choose the screen saver by right click the desktop>personalize
Choose the option ***"on resume,display logon screen"***. Then it will prompt for password when you wake your machine up. It doesn't matter if you choose Screen saver or not.

[image]